# Start Debugger in Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I need to debug an application that is started from a one-click install. (VS 2010, Excel 
VSTO with Office 7). Based on login credentials supplied to the one-click installer application, the user should see one of two splash pages. This all works fine on my machine, but when deployed, changing from the default to the second splash page results in an error.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to debug the process from within VS2010. I can attach to the login before entering the credentials, but I can't attach to Excel because it isn't launched until I click the OK button.

So, is there some way to have Excel, or rather, my code call the debugger as it is instantiated so I can figure out why my image resource isn't available in the deployed application?

Thanks.

Randy

Comment: Does the target machine have Visual Studio installed?

Comment: Nope. It's a dev server, but I believe the debugging person has to have Admin rights on it, and that ain't gonna happen.

Comment: Good that you got the issue solved but as a FYI you do not need admin rights, you just need to [be a member of `Debugger Users` for your user.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291232%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 143, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Comment: oh... was that so simple!? ! :) did not know it.

Comment: Yeah, and try finding that in the documentation! Maybe my Google-fu is weak.

Comment: I ought to vote myself down one for not simply looking at the class documentation. Oh well.

Comment: and System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break to breakpoint at the current location

Comment: Documentation says "Launches and attaches a debugger to the process.". But which debugger will be launched if I have multiple (VS, windbg, cdb...) and want a specific one of those?

Comment: @KFL I know this is an old post; when it hits launch(), a dialog will pop up asking what you want to debug with.

Answer (score 10):

### Most simple

To force a breakpoint from code use:

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

### When application wasn't started inside Visual Studio (including remote debugging)

Sometimes the application can't be started from Visual Studio and still needs to be debugged. I am using this code to check if Visual Studio is running and provide a way to attach it to Visual Studio.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

....

// get debugger processes
Process[] procName1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv");

// get remote debugging processes
Process[] procName2 = Process.GetProcessesByName("msvsmon"); 

// If Visual Studio or remote debug are running halt the application by showing a MessageBox and give opportunity to attach the debugger
if (procName1.Length > 0 || procName2.Length > 0)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, "Force breakpoint?", "Wait for debugger attach", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        // Force a breakpoint when the debugger became attached
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // force a breakpoint
    }
}
```

Today I needed a solution for a console app. Here it is:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

....

// Wait for debugger attach and force breakpoint
// for a console app
//
if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) // not needed when debugger is already attached
{
    /// for "eternal" wait (~ 68 years) use: 
    ///     int waitTimeout = int.MaxValue 
    int waitTimeout = 60; 

    // get debugger processes
    Process[] procName1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("devenv");

    // get remote debugging processes
    Process[] procName2 = Process.GetProcessesByName("msvsmon");

    // If Visual Studio or remote debug are running halt the application by showing an message and give opportunity to attach the debugger
    if (procName1.Length > 0 || procName2.Length > 0)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Visual studio is running | Force breakpoint? (Attach the debugger before pressing any key!)");
            Console.WriteLine("[Y]es, [No]");

            DateTime beginWait = DateTime.Now;
            while (!Console.KeyAvailable && DateTime.Now.Subtract(beginWait).TotalSeconds < waitTimeout)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(250); // sleep 1/4 second
            }

            if (!Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                break; // timeout elapsed without any kepress
                //<----------
            }

            var key = Console.ReadKey(false);
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
            {
                if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); // force a breakpoint
                    break; // leave the while(true)
                    //<----------
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No debugger attached");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
            else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.N)
            {
                break; // leave the while(true)
                //<----------
            }
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Juan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7276957/1574221) is the best if you have Visual Studio Installed. but if the target machne does not have it you may need to put in some kind of pause (I normally will put a dialog box as the first thing in main that makes it wait for me to attach) then use a [remote debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) to attach to it on your machine

Comment: Agreed. Its an ugly thing when you install VS on production machines :-D

Comment: This isn't even a production machine. But, I guess they see it as a test of rolling out to production -- meaning that the build manager is the only one who can deploy to the dev server. That's why I can't do any remote debugging.

Answer (score 0):

you could attach to Excel if it was running long enough but seriously I doubt the error is there.

you could attach to running applications/processes and if symbols are available (debug build) you can really debug, but the application has to live long enough for you to select it for attaching.

I think, from what you are saying, that what you need is proper exception and error logging, anything like Log4Net or NLog which stores everything (stack trace, exception details...) at every exception, so you would clearly identify what the real issue is.

Comment: The error is in a VSTO add-in for Excel; and it happens so soon in the process that there's no way to attach to it before the error's already bitten. Again, I can run the app from my machine without getting an error. It's only those using the app from the dev server that see the error.