# EF seed method does not save custom Identity user

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

Using this [Tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/) I try to implement Identity System in my web API Application, So i customize `UserIdentity` And `UserManager` and in `Seed` method of EF, Try to generate sample data Like This:

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new MedicalContext()));            
        var appUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>
        {
            new ApplicationUser{FirstName="admin",LastName="admin",UserName="admin",Email = "taiseer.joudeh@gmail.com",EmailConfirmed = true,DivisionID=1,Division=divisions[0],PhoneNumber="876543"},
            new ApplicationUser{FirstName="Mahdi",LastName="Mahdavi",UserName="mahdi",Email = "LKJHGF.joudeh@gmail.com",EmailConfirmed = true,DivisionID=0,Division=divisions[1],PhoneNumber="98765434567"}
        };
        var adminresult = manager.Create(appUsers[0], "admin");
```

for password if I Using `admin` password user creation faild because of using less than 6 character password and rest of my `Seed` Method run. But when using Correct Pass my application Stuck in `Create` Methode of `UserManager` and Without any Exception rest of `Seed` doesn't run.(it's seems Stuck in a loop or somthing)

Comment: Actually no matter i using my Custom `manager` & `identity user` OR Default `UserManager` & `IdentityUser`, Problem Still Happen

Comment: can you show us the definition of `appUsers[0]`

Comment: @erkaner add definition...

Comment: Please, debug and see what's really going on. To launch the debugger you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276936/start-debugger-in-code

Comment: @JotaBe actually i debug Seed Method, and on create function debug Stucke in somthing and redirect me to Browser... in `fireBug`  i see my first service call still wating for server Response and never stop until closing window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found it.... i should replace this:

```
var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new MedicalContext()));
```

with This:

```
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
var manager = new UserManager(store);
```